# Passing in parameters with submit_tag in RoR

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my view file I have:

```
enter code here
<% @range_array.each{|dataElement| %>
        <th>
            <% i = i+1 %>
            <%= form_tag({:controller => "scores", :action => "scores"}, :method => "get")      do %>
            <%= submit_tag(dataElement, :name => i) %>
            <% end %>
        </th>
        <% } %>
```

In controller I try to call it:

```
enter code here
 @range = params[:name].to_i
```

But when I try to use the @range variable it is always 0 regardless of which button I press, in the new url it does seem to pass the "i" value

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field.

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "scores", :action => "scores"}, :method => "get")      do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :name, :value => i %>
<%= submit_tag(dataElement) %>
<% end %>
```